# Colour packages beyond xcolor

Tags: color, packages

Am using `Texlive Version 2017.20180305-1` on `Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (Bionic Beaver)`.

I want to use more colours than the  19 named RGB colours from `\usepackage{xcolor}`.  What can I use?  I have seen mentions of packages `dvipsnames`, `svgnames`, and `x11names`.

Going beyond `\usepackage{xcolor}` gives me

```
! LaTeX Error: File `dvipsnames.sty' not found.
! LaTeX Error: File `svgnames.sty' not found.
! LaTeX Error: File `x11names.sty' not found.
```

when using `lualatex`.  They do not seem to be standard built-in package that come with latex.

Comment: these are not packages but xcolor options, try e.g. `\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}`

Comment: Good.  Does `x11names` give the largest number of colours?

Comment: you do not need to restrict to the predfined names in these options you can declare any name you want to be any rgb or cmyk color defined by suitable values

Comment: Fine.  Thus I can have the predefined names available, and then any user-defined or style-defined as well.

Comment: yes or no name at all and just use values directly `\color[rgb]{0.9,0.15,0.3}` will be some sort of red

Comment: What happens if I use `\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}` and there are conflicts where same name is used more than once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [xcolor manual](https://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/macros/latex/contrib/xcolor/xcolor.pdf): [Note that there are some conflicts between these options. For example, `x11names` and `dvipsnames` both define `Magenta`, but not as the exact same color. Consult the manual for conflict resolution.]

`\usepackage{xcolor}` provides the base colors
[image]

`\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}` provides additional:
[image]

`\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}` provides additional:
[image]
[image]

`\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}` provides additional:
[image]
[image]